# Why do access keys not work in this instance

Tags: c#, winforms

I was toying around with access keys and MenuStrips in c# and I ran into a problem that I couldn't find an answer to. I know Visual Studios has a quick and easy drag and drop to add a MenuStrip onto a form but I wanted to learn more *behind the scenes* so to say. This is the almost working code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MenuStripTest
{
     class MainClass
     {
          private static Form mainForm = new Form();
          private static Button testButton = new Button();
          private static MenuStrip menuStrip = new MenuStrip();
          private static ToolStripMenuItem fileMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem();
          private static ToolStripMenuItem fileNewButton = new ToolStripMenuItem();

          public static void Main()
          {
               // testButton
               testButton.Location = new Point(100, 100);
               testButton.Text = "&Test";
               testButton.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

               // menuStrip
               menuStrip.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
               menuStrip.Items.Add(fileMenu);

               // fileNewButton
               fileNewButton.Text = "&New";
               fileNewButton.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

               // fileMenu
               fileMenu.Text = "File";
               fileMenu.DropDownItems.Add(fileNewButton);

               // mainForm
               mainForm.Width = 500;
               mainForm.Height = 500;
               mainForm.KeyPreview = true;
               mainForm.MainMenuStrip = menuStrip;
               mainForm.Controls.Add(menuStrip);
               mainForm.Controls.Add(testButton);

               Application.Run(mainForm);
          }

          private static void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               MessageBox.Show("Event Executed");
          }
     }
}
```

This code **almost** does what I'd like. I can press ALT+t and the MessageBox shows up. However when I press ALT+n the `fileMenu` ToolStripMenuItem gets focus, but the `fileNewButton` control is never clicked and as a result the MessageBox is not launched. I have read the Microsoft docs on this and can't find any explanation for this behavior and the internet isn't showing much either. I can assume that maybe the DropDown isn't focused or rendered, but I really have no idea. Could someone please explain this behavior and what I am missing for this to function the way I want it to. Thanks!

In case it makes a difference, this code was compiled with csc.exe

Comment: Try ALT + F and then ALT + N. This works.

Comment: @Oguz Ozgul So this works although it's not really the functionality I had in mind. Plus Why does the File Menu already have an access key associated to it. I didn't specifically designate one, and I've not been able to find a list for default access keys

Comment: If not specified explicitly (with & as you already did), the initials become the quick access key with ALT automatically.  I added a Project menu to your form, and ALT+P opened that new menu.

Comment: I have found a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the confusion between & (The shortcut key for the menu item) and the shortcut key combination, also known as [keyboard accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/windows/win32/menurc/keyboard-accelerators) which is handled window-wise and provides direct execution of a menu command.

If a short-cut key is not specified explicitly (with & as you already did for "New"), the initials become the quick access key with ALT automatically.

This is because when a menu item is accessed via pressing consecutive keys (not a combination), the [ToolStripDropDown.ProcessDialogKey](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ToolStripDropDown.cs,c81e8063f1c20917) method handles it and selects the appropriate menu item in the drop-down and fires the click event.

When a keyboard accelerator is assigned to the menu item, though, the [ToolStripManager.ProcessCmdKey](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ToolStripManager.cs,e943c7d149a5f505) handles it and finds and calls the target menu item.

This is the reason for the behavior you are experiencing, and it is by design.

You can see this for yourself by just breaking in your event handler and by examining the call stack, when invoked through ALT+F and +N, and then this time by the assigned keyboard accelerator, let's say ALT+N directly.

Consider the following new menu items being added yo your form.

```
private static ToolStripMenuItem projectMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem();
private static ToolStripMenuItem projectPropertiesMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

And they being populated like:

```
projectMenu.Text = "Project";
projectPropertiesMenuItem.Text = "Properties";
projectPropertiesMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

menuStrip.Items.Add(projectMenu);
projectMenu.DropDownItems.Add(projectPropertiesMenuItem);
```

You can see when running the form, ALT+P activates the new menu even though we did not specify a shortcut for it. The [ToolStripMenuItem](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ToolStripMenuItem.cs) handles this automatically.

But we can assign a keyboard accelerator to our menu item like this:

```
projectPropertiesMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Alt | Keys.P;
```

Which

1. Removes ALT+P shortcut handling from the owner;
2. Sets the global shortcut for the nested menu item;
3. And also shows it next to the menu text (bonus)

[image]

Comment: huh, that's actually pretty interesting. If I may ask, where did you find this documentation, like what page, or did you figure out through experimentation. I'm at work currently, but I will test this out when I get back home where my code is and mark this as the answer if it fixes the issue

Comment: Saw it in the source code ToolStripMenuItem. Experimentation also confirms this. The link to the source code is in my answer.  I am also adding some more information on this